# Cannot search meteor packages in iron-cli project

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor iron app I generated. In the eventedmind screencast the instructor searches packages with `iron search ^accounts` to see all meteor packages. When I run that though

```
$ iron search ^accounts
> meteor search app bin build config readme.md
```

How can I search for meteor packages with the iron command line tool? I'm using iron-meteor version 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need iron to search meteor packages. Use meteor search:

```
meteor search sometext
```

Comment: you're right. this may be a different question but when I want to search for only packages that start with the word accounts I get an error: `meteor search ^accounts` I get the error: `search: too many arguments.`

Comment: Not sure if meteor search supports regex. You can chain it to a script to do regex search if that's important.